# How do i remove the navigation in android studio?

Tags: android, xml

How do i hide or remove the navigation at the top of my  android studio? just like in the shown below picture?

[image]

here is my .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

   
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/appName"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you have navigationview rt?

Comment: navigationview, what? in my res folder?

Comment: in your style.xml set the parent of AppTheme: Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's your newly created project

In your `styles.xml` change parent theme from

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--style goes here-->
</style>
```

to

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--style goes here-->
</style>
```